# Sending a POST request with a request body just as a string

Tags: go

I have a page setup on my webserver with an 'email address' box and a submit button. I have it so when it is submitted, it sends a post request to check if it exists in my database. I have been using Go to try and send this POST request. However, I need to send the request body as the following:

```
demo_mail=<email>
```

I haven't found anything remotely useful online, only posts asking how to send the data with JSON rather than a string. I currently have the following code which runs but fails to send the POST request with the post data above.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "<MY PAGE>", ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString("demo_mail=" + email)))
            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            req.Header.Set("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8")
            req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36")



            resp, err := client.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                 color.Red("Error.")
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)


            if strings.Contains(string(body), "Success") {
                fmt.Println("Email exists")
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Fail")
            }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body you expect is actually correctly sent but maybe not in the way you want:

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
...
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...

17
demo_mail=<foo@bar.com>
0
```

Since you've wrapped your string into a `io.NopCloser` it will assume that the length is not known up-front. It will therefore use chunked transfer encoding to send each chunk returned from the `io.Reader` prefixed by its length and once everything done the final chunk with length 0.

If you don't want to have this behavior you need to provide a buffer where the length is known up-front. This can be done by simply removing the `ioutil.NopCloser` around the `bytes.NewBufferString`:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "<MY PAGE>", bytes.NewBufferString("demo_mail=" + email))
```

With this the request will use `Content-length` instead of chunked transfer encoding and the body will only contain the string:

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
...
Content-Length: 23
...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...

demo_mail=<foo@bar.com>
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help :) However, i've tried the POST via 'Postman' for chrome and it works absolutely fine but for some strange reason it doesn't want to work via golang. I also tried using the code provided by Postman, but it just keeps throwing 'Redirect 200' and i'm really stuck as to why

Comment: *"...doesn't want to work ...."* - this is not really sufficient information to debug a problem. Apart from that, this looks like a new question. I recommend to  compare what gets exactly send and received by the working and non-working version, for example with a packet capture.

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct about that `ioutil.NopCloser` thing: please see what the manual for `net/http.Request.Write` says. The correct way of getting rid of chunked encoding (if it's _really_ needed, which, I admit, is questionable for an apparently novice programmer) is to simply set the `ContentType` field of the created `http.Request` value to the total length of the body to be sent. In the OP's case it should amount to merely calling `Len()` on the buffer created by `bytes.NewBufferString`.

Comment: @kostix: `go doc http.NewRequest` states that if the body is of type `bytes.Buffer` (and some more) it will automatically set the `Content-Length` and that with most other types of body it will instead set the length to -1. The last will result in the use of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` as documented in `http.Request.Write`.